# Updating state in react

Tags: reactjs

I couldn't get the idea of updating state in react.

```
state = {
    products : []
};
```

---

```
handleProductUpVote = (productId) => {
     const nextProducts = this.state.products.map((product) 
    => {
     if (product.id === productId) {
         return Object.assign({}, product, {
             votes: product.votes + 1,
         });
     } else {
         return product;
     }
     });
     this.setState({
         products: nextProducts,
     });
     }
```

Why we need to clone the object? Can we simply write

```
if (product.id === productId) {
      product.votes =  
      product.votes + 1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

State updates can happen asynchronously, and delegating actual change of the state helps to ensure that things won't go wrong. Passing a new Object with the change also lets react make a (shallow) check to see which parts of the state were updated, and which components relying on it should be rerendered.